# Inno Setup Compiler check boxes

Tags: inno-setup

Why does Inno setup compiler have some check boxes disabled? See attachment.[image: ![Showing image of check boxes disabled]

Comment: What happens if you untick the first option?

Comment: I unticked the top check box and the check boxes were OK. Thanks! I can't believe I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is untick the top check box. Then the others will become enabled.

Comment: Worth noting, that one should not uncheck the top box. Using Start Menu groups is against Windows Guidelines since at least Windows 8. There should be one icon per application in Start menu only.